# How to properly process images with mixed noise types

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, noise-reduction

The picture with noise is like this.
[Noised picture: Image3.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw61d.png)

I was doing image processing in MatLab with some built-in and self-implemented filters.

I have already tried a combination of bilateral, median and gaussian. bilateral and gaussian code are at the end of this post.

```matlab
img3 = double(imread('Image3.bmp')); % this is the noised image
lena = double(imread('lena_gray.jpg')); % this is the original one

img3_com = bilateral(img3, 3, 2, 80);
img3_com = medfilt2(img3_com, [3 3], 'symmetric');
img3_com = gaussian(img3_com, 3, 0.5);
img3_com = bilateral(double(img3_com), 6, 100, 13);
SNR3_com = snr(img3_com,img3_com - lena); % 17.1107
```

However, the result is not promising with SNR of only 17.11.

[Filtered image: img3_com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p34p.png)

The original picture is like this.

[Clean original image: lena_gray.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH3Da.jpg)

Could you please give me any possible ideas about how to process it? Like what noise generators generated the noised image and what filtering methods or image processing method I can use to deal with it. Appreciate!!!

My bilateral function `bilateral.m`

```
function img_new = bilateral(img_gray, window, sigmaS, sigmaI)

imgSize = size(img_gray);

img_new = zeros(imgSize);

for i = 1:imgSize(1)
    for j = 1:imgSize(2)
        sum = 0;
        simiSum = 0;
                    
        for a = -window:window
            for b = -window:window
                x = i + a;
                y = j + b;
                p = img_gray(i,j);
                q = 0;
                if x < 1 || y < 1 || x > imgSize(1) || y > imgSize(2)
%                     q=0;
                    continue;
                else
                    q = img_gray(x,y);
                end
                 gaussianFilter = exp( - double((a)^2 + (b)^2)/ (2 * sigmaS^2  ) - (double(p-q)^2)/ (2 * sigmaI^2 ));
%                 gaussianFilter = gaussian((a^2 + b^2)^(1/2), sigma) * gaussian(abs(p-q), sigma);
                sum = sum + gaussianFilter * q;
                simiSum = simiSum + gaussianFilter;
            end
        end
        img_new(i,j) = sum/simiSum;
    end     
end

% disp SNR
lena = double(imread('lena_gray.jpg'));
SNR1_4_ = snr(img_new,img_new - lena);
disp(SNR1_4_);
```

My gaussian implementation `gaussian.m`

```
function img_gau = gaussian(img, hsize, sigma)

h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma);
img_gau = conv2(img,h,'same');

% disp SNR
lena = double(imread('lena_gray.jpg'));
SNR1_4_ = snr(img_gau,img_gau - lena);
disp(SNR1_4_);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is too broad for this site. You should ask something more specific, including a [mcve]. Also, `bilateral` and `gaussian` do not seem to be standard Matlab / Image Processing Toolbox functions

Comment: If there was a final solution, then all these filters wold not exists....

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you! This is my first try in Stack Overflow. I'll try to make my question more specific.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you! I totally agree. That's why I was trying to combine filters and image processing techniques to get a higher SNR. I was wondering how to analyse the original image to judge the way of combination.